# d3 chart: how to set multiple css properties for d3 chart

Tags: css, d3.js, charts

```
svg.append("text")      
      .attr("x", width / 2 )
          .attr("y", 0)
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size",12)
          .text("Title of Diagram");
```

I wanted to use only a single style and set all CSS properties in that.

e.g

.style(properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, you can pass a style object into the `.style()` function with d3.js V3:

```js
const width = 200;

const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${width}`);
    

svg.append("text")      
    .attr("x", width / 2 )
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style({
      'alignment-baseline': "hanging",
      "text-anchor": "middle",
      "font-size": 12,
    })
    .text("Title of Diagram");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
</svg>
```

With V4 and V5, the d3.js team split out this so-called 'd3-selection-multi' functionality out of the main distribution, but you can still include this module and use it like this:

Note: you need to change from `.style()` to `.styles({...})`

Note: this 'd3-selection-multi' module also enables you to set multiple attributes with an object with `.attrs({...})`

Note: you can also combine this with data binding

```js
const width = 200;

const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${width}`);


svg.append("text")      
    .attrs({
      "x": width / 2,
      "y": 0
    })
    .styles({
      'alignment-baseline': "hanging",
      "text-anchor": "middle",
      "font-size": 12,
    })
    .text("Title of Diagram");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js">
</script>
<svg>
</svg>
```

The final option is to pass in your style string directly to `.attr()` but of course this overwrites the entire style attribute with your string, so you can't use it twice on one element:

```js
const width = 200;

const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${width}`);


svg.append("text")      
    .attr('x', width / 2)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('style',
      `alignment-baseline: hanging;
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-size: 12;`
    )
    .text("Title of Diagram");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
</svg>
```