# Why am I receiving the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'transition')" after upgrading from D3 v3 to v5

Tags: d3.js

I have upgraded d3 from v3 to v5 on a simple visual.  I've made most of the tweaks including those to d3.scv.arc and d3.layout.pie but I'm getting the following error message:

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'transition')"

Here is the v3 code working:  https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/b06wLcm8/141/
Here is the v5 code so far including the error:  https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/hmnyu7bs/1/

Can anyone help with this please?

here's the current v5 code

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 30,  
    bottom: 10,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



var outerRadius = 45;
var innerRadius = outerRadius - 5;
var color = ['#ec1561', '#2a3a46', '#ec1561'];


var data = [

  {
    "value": 90,
    "variance": 6

  }
]



var percent = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  })


var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .sort(null);


var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(35)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(35)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);


//The circle is following this
var arcDummy = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius((outerRadius - innerRadius) / 2 + innerRadius)
  .outerRadius((outerRadius - innerRadius) / 2 + innerRadius)
  .startAngle(0);


var arcLine = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
 // .cornerRadius(10)
  .startAngle(0);


//background
var path = svg.append('path')
  .attr({
    d: arc,
    fill: color[1],
    opacity: 0.2
  });


var path2 = svg.append('path')
  .attr({
    d: arc2,
    fill: color[1],
    opacity: 0.2
  });



var pathForeground = svg.append('path')
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0
  })
  .attr({
    d: arcLine,
    fill: "#137A76"

  });

//Dummy Arc for Circle
var pathDummy = svg.append('path')
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0
  })
  .attr({
    d: arcDummy,
    fill: color[0]
  });

var endCircle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr({
    r: 0,
    transform: 'translate(0,' + (-outerRadius + 7) + ')',
    stroke: color[0],
    'stroke-width': 5,
    fill: color[2]
  });

var middleTextCount = svg.append('text')
  .datum(0)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d + '%';
  })

  .attr({
    class: 'middleText',
    'text-anchor': 'middle',
    dy: 0,
    dx: 75,
    fill: '#ec1561',
    'font-size': '20px'

  });
  
  
  svg
  .data(data)
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("width", 8)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    if (d.variance < 0 ) {
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Red_Arrow_Down.svg/2048px-Red_Arrow_Down.svg.png"
    } else {
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Green_Arrow_Up.svg/1200px-Green_Arrow_Up.svg.png"
    }
  })

  
  
    svg 
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("y", -25)
  .attr("x", -25)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
   
      return "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2879/2879567.png"
  })
  
      //add icon

  
  
  
  svg 
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("x", 50)
  .text("Positive Feedback")
  
  
    svg 
  .data(data)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "varweek")
  .attr("y", 27)
  .attr("x", 62)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.variance + '% vs last week';
  })


var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "100%")
  .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

gradient.append("svg:stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#DA0D91")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 0.05);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#DA0D91")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);






var arcTweenOld = function(transition, percent, oldValue) {
  transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {

    var newAngle = (percent / 100) * (2 * Math.PI);

    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

    var interpolateCount = d3.interpolate(oldValue, percent);


    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      var pathForegroundCircle = arcLine(d);

      middleTextCount.text(Math.floor(interpolateCount(t)) + '%');

      var pathDummyCircle = arcDummy(d);
      var coordinate = pathDummyCircle.split("L")[1].split("A")[0];

      endCircle.attr('transform', 'translate(' + coordinate + ')');

      return pathForegroundCircle;
    };
  });
};

var oldValue = 0;

var animate = function() {
  pathForeground.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .ease('cubic')
    .call(arcTweenOld, percent, oldValue);

  oldValue = percent;
  //percent=(Math.random() * 60) + 20;
  // setTimeout(animate,3000);
};

setTimeout(animate, 0);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Georama:ital@1&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #1B1F2A;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Georama', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

.widget {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:350px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: #222D3A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #06060d;

}

.header{
    background-color: #29384D;
    height:40px;
    color:#929DAF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #06060d;
}

.chart-container{
    padding:25px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1) );
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1) );
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Georama', sans-serif;
  fill: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}


.varweek
{

  fill: white;
  font-size: 9px;
  opacity: 0.25
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" class="chart-container">

    </div>
```

Comment: You can't set multiple attributes with an object in d3v5 as you could in d3v3 when using either .attr or .style, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62894874/7106086) for a similar issue with .style. You'll have to either use d3-selection-multi or break each attribute into its own .attr call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should take a look to the returns of methods

For example you wrote

```
var pathForeground = svg.append('path')
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0
  })
  .attr({
    d: arcLine,
    fill: "#137A76"
  });
```

I didn't look it up, but it looks like `.attr` doesnt return the object, so now `pathForeground` turns into `null`.
You can split it up in the defining part and set attr part.

```
var pathForeground = svg.append('path');
// new line
pathForeground 
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0
  })
  .attr({
    d: arcLine,
    fill: "#137A76"
  });
```

With all properties.  This is what is causing your error. I didn't look in the changelogs.

Comment: pathForeground will be the same selection either way, append("path") returns a selection of the newly appended path, attr also returns a selection of that path, after modifying the path itself.